# generating kickstart ISO for post-fd OSes (eg CentOS 8) and using it in packer vsphere-iso invocation

Tags: iso, packer, vsphere, centos8

I'm having a problem specifying the kickstart source on my Packer vsphere-iso template build. I suspect I'm close, but I'm still seeing that the ks is not found during boot and the install goes Interactive at that point.

In my vsphere-iso packer, I'm saying:

```
{
  "variables":
  {
:
    "ks"                : "CentOS-8-x86_64.ks",
:
    "cd_label"          : "OEMDRV",
    "vmipaddress"       : "10.1.8.47",
    "vmnetmask"         : "255.255.254.0",
    "vmgateway"         : "10.1.9.254",
    "vmnameserver"      : "10.1.9.210",
:
  },

  "builders":
  [
    {
      "type"                 : "vsphere-iso",
:
      "boot_wait"            : "5s",
      "boot_command":
      [
        "<esc>",
        " linux ks=hd:LABEL={{user `cd_label`}}:/{{user `ks`}}",
        " ip={{user `vmipaddress`}}::{{user `vmgateway`}}:{{user `vmnetmask`}}:template:eth0:none",
        " nameserver={{user `vmnameserver`}}",
        " biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0",
        "<enter>",
        "<wait>"
      ],
:
      "cd_files"         : ["ks/{{user `ks`}}"],
      "cd_label"         : "{{user `cd_label`}}",
:
:
}
```

No, I can't refer it back to an HTTP URL.  Trust me, I can't !

I can confirm that `ks/CentOS-8-x86_64.ks` exists, so I half assume anaconda should find it.  Mounting a generated ISO image out of the packer cache dir on the DS shows that yes, it is being built with a non-empty ks file on-board.

I don't think the devname tunings (for *actually* consistent device naming) is causing a problem here, but I don't discount it.

The boot command ends up rendered as (manual copy, watch for typos):

```
boot:   linux ks=hd:LABEL=OEMDRV:/CentOS-8-x86_64.ks ip=10.1.8.47::10.1.9.254:255.255
.254.0:template:eth0:none nameserver=10.1.9.210 biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0
Loading ... failed: No such file or directory
boot: _
```

Something's not right.  It's gotta be a dumb typo, as I've got the typical "at wits' end" feeling that always precedes a typo fix.

Can you help me spot it?

Comment: You sure there shouldn't be a ./ before ks for cd_files entry?

Comment: I'm sure!  The ISO *is* being generated, seems valid, and contains exactly the one ks file as hoped.  So that's maybe not it, but good thinking.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem. I didn't want to use HTTP because, reasons.

I wasn't able to get the `ks=hd:LABEL=OEMDRV` working.

I switched to using `cdrom` but for some odd reason, I had to explicitly specify `/dev/sr1` when using `cdrom`. `sr0` would be the CentOS ISO i'm booting from, so `sr1` is the second ISO (that Packer builds and uploads on the fly)

Following your naming convention, I used the equivalent of `inst.ks=cdrom:/dev/sr1:/CentOS-8-x86_64.ks` and was able to get it working.

Tested using `CentOS-8.2.2004-x86_64-minimal.iso`